# Understanding the exact sequence $\Bbb{Z}\to \text{Pic}(X)\to \text{Pic}(U)\to 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following is an exercise from pg 5 of [this document](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaseap/arith/notes/picard.pdf) on Picard Groups:

> Let $Z$ be a prime divisor in a smooth variety $X$, and let $U$ denote the complement $X\setminus Z$. Show that the sequence $$\Bbb{Z}\to \text{Pic}(X)\to \text{Pic}(U)\to 0$$ is exact. The map from $\Bbb{Z}\to \text{Pic}(X)$ is of the form $1\to Z$, where $Z$ is the previously chosen prime divisor.
>
> Now use this result to prove that $\text{Pic}(\Bbb{P}^n)=\Bbb{Z}$ for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

I may be doing this wrong, but I think the map from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\text{Pic}(X)$ is the zero map, as $Z$ corresponds to a principal divisor in $\text{Div}(X)$. Also, the map $\text{Pix}(X)\to \text{Pic}(U)$ is the identity map.

If both of these are true, which I don't think they are, then I have no way of proving that $\text{Pic}(\Bbb{P}^n)=\Bbb{Z}$. Am I understanding the exact sequence given above incorrectly.

Comment: Why do you think $Z$ is a principal divisor?

Comment: @EricWofsey- Isn't a prime divisor, which corresponds to an irreducible variety of codimension $1$, and hence an irreducible polynomial, also a principal divisor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Z$ has no reason to be a principal divisor, e.g if $Z \subset \Bbb P^2$ is a line. In any case you have a map $\Bbb Z \to Pic(X), 1 \mapsto [Z]$.

The map $Pic(X) \to Pic(U)$ is given by restriction :$D \mapsto D \cap U$ where $D$ is  a prime divisor and extend by linearity. In particular the composition is zero and your sequence is indeed exact. Surjectivity is because any divisor $D \subset U$ can be extended to a divisor $\tilde D \subset X$ (just take the closure).

Now $Pic(\Bbb A^n) = 0$ because $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a UFD. So you have a surjection $\Bbb Z \to Pic(\Bbb P^n)$ by taking the image of an hyperplane, and it's easy to see that this map is a bijection.

Comment: But the question itself says "let $Z$ be a prime divisor in a smooth variety $X$..."

Comment: @AyushKhaitan : sorry, I meant principal !! I edited for clarity.

Comment: Why is $Z\cap U$ a principal divisor in $U$? Let us take your example- let $Z$ be a line in $\Bbb{P}^2$. Then it will not be an element of the function field of any open subset of $\Bbb{P}^2$, as any element of the function field has to be a fraction of polynomials of the same degree. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan $Z \cap U = \emptyset$ so I am not sure I understand your comment.
Now if we take another open (say $V$) isomorphic to $\Bbb A^2 \subset \Bbb P^2$ then $Z \cap V$ is the zero set of some linear form which is indeed an element of $K(V)$. This is because any hypersurface in $\Bbb A^n$ is always given by the zero of a single polynomial. The description you made works only for $\Bbb P^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example is  when $X$ is a smooth  projective curve , say over $\mathbb C$.
Then a prime divisor is just a single point $P\in X$ and the group morphism $$j:\mathbb Z\to \operatorname {Pic(X)}:n\mapsto [nP]$$ is injective.
**Reason:** any principal divisor $$\operatorname {div}f=\sum n_iP_i\in \operatorname {Prin}(X)\subset \operatorname {Div(X)}$$ has degree $\sum n_i=0$, so that $nP$ can be principal only if $n=0.$
But is  $j$ surjective?

$\bullet$If the genus of $X$ is zero, i.e. if $X=\mathbb P^1$, we get an isomorphism $j:\mathbb Z\stackrel{\cong}{\to}\operatorname {Pic(X)}$
 **Reason:** $\operatorname {Pic(U)}=\operatorname {Pic(\mathbb A^1)}=0$ because $\mathcal O(\mathbb A^1)=\mathbb C[T]$ and a UFD has zero Picard group.

$\bullet \bullet$ If $X$ has positive genus $g$, then $j$ is not surjective.
**Reason:** $\operatorname {Pic(X)}$ is non denumerable. More precisely: the group $\operatorname {Pic(X)}$ can be endowed with the structure of a (non-connected) smooth complex variety of dimension $g$ (this is a non-trivial result).

**Remarks**
 1) Note carefully that the injectivity of $j$ prevents (for any value of the genus $g$) the group morphism $\operatorname {Pic(X)}\to \operatorname {Pic(U)}$ from being bijective (contrary to what you thought according to the ninth line of your question).
2) If $X$ is not a smooth projective curve $j$ has no reason to be injective.
The simplest counterexample is for $X=\mathbb A^1$: as I mentioned above $\operatorname {Pic}(\mathbb A^1)=0$, so that $j:\mathbb Z\to \operatorname {Pic}(\mathbb A^1)=0$ is definitely not injective!